# Writing photos (and other things) to disk and getting them later in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, filesystems, nsdata

I'm trying to write an image to disk:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* savePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo"];
    BOOL result = [data writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
    if(result) NSLog(@"Save of photo success!");
```

Then, later, I try to retrieve for a table view cell image:

```
    NSData* getPhoto = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[leaf content]];
    UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:getPhoto];
    cell.imageView.image = myImage;
```

Yes, I checked to make sure the [leaf content] returns the same NSString as savePath. What else could be the problem? `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[leaf content]];` returns nil....

EDIT: I am making the original data that I call writeToFile on this way:

```
NSData* dataToAdd = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

Thanks guys

Comment: How do you create your data object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your new filename is not a valid photo.

If you have an image named `file`, then you will be writing to the path `filephoto`, but i think what you want is something like `filephoto.jpg`... maybe you need a image file extension?

Or maybe the path isn't fully expanded...even though it is the same, its possible that you aren't giving `dataWithContentsOfFile:` an absolute path.

Those are my guesses.